# reverting p4 add -- not able to remove files from after doing recursive add with p4 reconcile -a

Tags: perforce

I have deleted the files from disk and now am not able to remove the files from appearing in default changelist `p4 revert -w` does not take default changelist. I have tried to edit default changlist with `p4 change` then deleted the change number. But sure enough the added files are back in default changelist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `p4 revert` to revert open files

You can edit a numbered changelist when creating it to move files into it from the default changelist, and you can edit a changelist during submit to exclude files from the submit (which will move them back into the default changelist), but files are *never* reverted as a side effect of editing a pending changelist.

You don't indicate in your question what problem exactly you ran into when trying to use `revert`, but you can indeed specify `default` as the changelist if needed.  Note that `-w` is not needed if you've already deleted the files yourself.

```
C:\Perforce\test\new_files>echo asdfasdf > foo

C:\Perforce\test\new_files>echo asdfasdf > bar

C:\Perforce\test\new_files>p4 reconcile -a ...
//stream/main/new_files/bar#1 - opened for add
//stream/main/new_files/foo#1 - opened for add

C:\Perforce\test\new_files>p4 revert -c default //...
//stream/main/new_files/bar#none - was add, abandoned
//stream/main/new_files/foo#none - was add, abandoned
```

Note that you also do not need to specify the `-c` flag unless you're trying to specifically revert files in one changelist without affecting others.  You can just specify an individual file:

```
C:\Perforce\test\new_files>p4 reconcile ...
//stream/main/new_files/bar#1 - opened for add
//stream/main/new_files/foo#1 - opened for add

C:\Perforce\test\new_files>p4 revert bar
//stream/main/new_files/bar#none - was add, abandoned
```

or use a wildcard to revert all open files (i.e. all files in all changelists, if `-c` is not specified):

```
C:\Perforce\test\new_files>p4 revert //...
//stream/main/new_files/foo#none - was add, abandoned
```

Comment: Thanks. I was trying : ```p4 revert -c default``` and missing on the wildcard //...                                                       
Usage: revert [ -a -n -k -w -c changelist# -C client ] [--remote=rmt] files...
Missing/wrong number of arguments

Comment: Note that the `files...` argument in the usage error does not have `[]` around it, which means it's required!  Usually a command where the file arg is optional will default to operating on *all* files, and because `revert` is potentially destructive you have to explicitly say what files you want to revert (i.e. `//...` if you want to revert everything).